# sencha: command not found

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I've installed Sencha by using the Terminal but I can't run if from the Terminal

```
samuel@samuel-pc:~/Downloads$ sudo ./SenchaCmd-6.5.0.180-linux-i386.sh -q
Starting Installer ...
The installation directory has been set to /root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.5.0.180.
Extracting files ...
Finishing installation ...
samuel@samuel-pc:~/Downloads$ sencha
sencha: command not found
```

Comment: You must set environment variable.

Comment: which variable? @DoNhuVy can you be more specific

Comment: Let's do like official document in my answer. At this time, I don't use Linux, therefore, you search `How to set environment variable on ....?`. It is nearly same with setting environment variable on Windows or macOS.

Answer (score 4):

Because you don't set environment variable.

> If running sencha results in the error message ***sencha: command not***
>   ***found*** on OSX/Linux or 'sencha' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file on Windows, follow
>   these steps: ...

This is official guide: https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/intro_to_cmd.html#intro_to_cmd_-_command_not_found